# Wrong string when passed to function

Tags: c, function

I've been trying the "How many days in a given month".

My `main` looks like this:

```
int main(void) {
    int numberOfDays, month = 0;
    char* input = (char*) malloc(10);

    printf("Please enter a month (\"1\", \"Jan\", \"January\", \"jan\" or \"january\" etc.):\n> ");
    scanf(" %s", input);
    selectMonth(input);

    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            numberOfDays = 31;  break;
        ...
        default:
            numberOfDays = 0;
            printf("Invalid month.\n");
    }
...
```

And `selectMonth`:

```
int selectMonth(char* input) {
    int month = 0;

    if (!strcasecmp(input, "jan") || !strcasecmp(input, "january") || !strcasecmp(input, "1")) {
        month = 1;
    }
    ...

    return month;
}
```

When I put the contents of `selectMonth` inside `main`, it works fine. But when I have a separate function for the else/ifs and return the month, the switch goes straight to the default case.
Why is that?

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
selectMonth(input);
```

The expression's result is not being assigned to `month`... so:

```
month = selectMonth(input);
```

Shall help resolve your forementioned issues.

Remember, C has *local scope variables*, so the `month` that you declare inside `selectMonth` is **not** the same `month` as the one declared in `main()`. Thus, the one in `main()` does never get any value other than zero, which it was initialized with.

Comment: That was quick! Thank you very much, I didn't notice that at all! I will mark your answer when I am able to in 10 minutes! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Dradee: No problem! Comment here if you have any other related issue :).